# Filling gaps in a proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the smooth map $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$. Consider a partition of $[a,b]$ 
$$
P=\{a=t_0<t_1<\ldots,<t_m\}
$$
Let's define 
$$
v=\sum_{k=1}^m|\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})|
$$
and 
$$
V(\gamma)=sup\{v(\gamma,P):P\text{ a partition of }[a,b]\}
$$
With this background established y pose my question now. I am trying to understand a step in a proof in Conway's complex analysis book (Proposition 1.3 in chapter IV). He begins with the definition of $v$ I have given
$$
v=\sum_{k=1}^m|\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})|
$$
but in the next line with no more explanation an integral appears
$$
=\sum_{k=1}^m\big|\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k}\gamma'(t)\,dt\big|
$$
the next lines are obvious
$$
\leq\sum_{k=1}^m\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k}\big|\gamma'(t)\big|\,dt
$$
$$
=\int_{t_{a}}^{b}\big|\gamma'(t)\big|\,dt
$$
he then states that therefore
$$
V(\gamma)\leq\int_a^b\big|\gamma'(t)\big|\,dt
$$
I don't see how this follows. How does this follow, and where did the integral come?

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:  $\int_a^b f'(x) \, dx = f(b) - f(a)$.

Comment: Also, you have a typo in the definition of $v$.  I'm guessing $v = \sum_{k =1}^m  |\gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1})|$.

Comment: Tell us _all_ the hypotheses regarding $\gamma$. From what you've said there is no reason that integral should even _exist_. There must be something you're not telling us...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich in the theorem $\gamma$ is assumed to have continuous first derivative

Comment: You should really add that to the question - as it stands the question is simply wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In integral appears by the Fundamental Theorem of Caluculus for real variables:
$$
\gamma(t_{k})-\gamma(t_{k-1})=\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k}}\gamma'(t)dt.
$$

To see why the final inequality follows, note that you have proved 
$$
v(\gamma,P)\leq\int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt
$$
for all $P$. Hence, you may take the $\sup$ of these to conclude that
$$
v(\gamma)\leq\int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt
$$

Comment: The FTC has _hypotheses_ - from what we're given in the OP there is no  reason to suppose FTC holds, in fact no reason that the integral of $\gamma'$ should even _exist_.

Comment: You're right. I was assuming $\gamma$ is a smooth curve.

Comment: Of course it seems likely that it _is_ a smooth curve. But it's not smooth until we have hypotheses saying so...

Comment: David you are right, smoothnes is precisely the assumption